# how to convert exponential variable into a full decimal variable in php?

Tags: php

I noticed that when I use postman for passing parameter to an API endpoint, I'm receiving an exponential form.

e.g
in postman I was passing

```
$variable = 0.0000002;
```

but when i var_dump it in php side I get

```
float(2.0E-7);
```

what if I want to convert it to 2 decimal point ?

Comment: Firstly, you have an important misunderstanding here: in the computer's memory, the number is neither of those formats, it's a binary floating point number. What `var_dump` shows you is just one way of writing it; what you need to think about is what you want to *do* with that number. Secondly, that number to two decimal places would just be zero, so your question doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: Simply use `number_format()` instead of `var_dump`